# Lsp-mode cannot find <linux/init.h> file with Linux kernel source project

Tags: lsp-mode

I installed Lsp-mode with open Linux source kernel,but got this error even if I add `lsp-workspace-folder-add` the right file.

```
LSP :: Connected to [clangd:8185/starting /home/lela/linux-3.0.35].
LSP :: clangd:8185 initialized successfully in folders: (/home/lela/linux-3.0.35)
'linux/init.h' file not found [pp_file_not_found]
LSP :: Connected to [clangd:8185 /home/lela/linux-3.0.35].
Too many errors emitted, stopping now [fatal_too_many_errors]
'linux/init.h' file not found [pp_file_not_found] [2 times]
Beginning of buffer
Too many errors emitted, stopping now [fatal_too_many_errors]
Mark set
```

I tried add workspace-folder as :
`M-x lsp-workspace-folder-add` 
`M-x lsp-workspace-folder-open`
as a result got this:

```
/home/lela/linux-3.0.35/include
/home/lela/linux-3.0.35
```

How can i figure it out?

Comment: This is a question about how to configure clangd, rather than about Emacs. Check the [clangd documentation](https://clangd.llvm.org/config).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution : generate the `compile_commands.json`file with the  latest kernel source code `script/gen_compile_commands.py` file.
It fix my error.